# AngularJS + Bootstrap dismissable alert

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a dismissable alert using AngularJS and Bootstrap
This is my code
**HTML**

```
<div class="col-lg-9" ng-controller="manageProfile">
    <form style="margin-top:80px">
        <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" ng-controller="dismiss" ng-show="successAlert == true">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close" ng-click="dismissSuccess()">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
            Username Changed!
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Display Name</label>
            <input type="text" ng-model="currentName" class="form-control" placeholder="Display Name">
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-md" ng-click="changeName()">Change Username!</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

**AngularJS**

```
profile.controller('manageProfile', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.changeName = function() {
        var user = Parse.User.current();
        user.setUsername($scope.currentName);
        user.save(null, {
            success: function(user) {
                $scope.successAlert = true;
                $scope.$apply();
            },
            error: function(error) {
                $scope.errorAlert = true;
                $scope.$apply();
            }
        });
    };
}]);

profile.controller('dismiss', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.dismissSuccess = function(){
        $scope.successAlert = false;
        $scope.$apply();
    }
    $scope.dismissError = function(){
        $scope.errorAlert = false;
    }
}]);
```

The concept is after I changed my username by clicking the `Change Username` button, it will set the value of `$scope.successAlert` to `true` and showing the dismissable bootstrap alert. After that, if I close the alert, it will trigger the `dismissSuccess()` and set the value of `$scope.successAlert` to `false`, so that if I change my username again (without reloading the page) it will show the alert again.
However, this code won't let me get the result I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know its a very old question. But I faced the same issue and the question is still open yet.
Here is how I solved it..

changes in html

```
<div class="col-lg-9" ng-controller="manageProfile">
    <form style="margin-top:80px">
        <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" ng-controller="dismiss" ng-show="profile.successAlert == true">
            <button type="button" class="close"  aria-label="Close" ng-click="dismissSuccess()">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
            Username Changed!
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Display Name</label>
            <input type="text" ng-model="currentName" class="form-control" placeholder="Display Name">
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-md" ng-click="changeName()">Change Username!</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

I change this line `ng-show="successAlert == true"` to `ng-show="profile.successAlert == true"`

**And remove `data-dismiss="alert"`**. This is the main problem. The default functionality of this code is to remove the `alert parent div` completely from `DOM`.

If `alert div` is removed from `DOM` then how can we `hide` or `show` it.

A little bit changes in Javascript code

```
var profile = angular.module('myApp', []);

profile.controller('manageProfile', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.profile = {}; // make an empty object. This is a separate topic why should we add this. This is best practice.
    $scope.changeName = function() {
        /*var user = Parse.User.current();
        user.setUsername($scope.currentName);
        user.save(null, {
            success: function(user) {
                $scope.successAlert = true;
                $scope.$apply();
            },
            error: function(error) {
                $scope.errorAlert = true;
                $scope.$apply();
            }
        });*/
        $scope.profile.successAlert = true;// I supposed your save call is success so show the success alert
    };
}]);

profile.controller('dismiss', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.dismissSuccess = function(){
        $scope.profile.successAlert = false;
        //$scope.$apply();// commented this line to prevent "$apply already in progress" thow 
    }
    $scope.dismissError = function(){
        $scope.profile.errorAlert = false;
    }
}]);
```

Checkout the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/31040/